# Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 multiple monitor issue

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

I'm having issues trying to setup my dual monitor setup in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 (GNOME 3.20).

I use my external monitor in portrait mode as primary screen (Dell 2209WAf - 1680x1050) and my laptop as secondary screen (ASUS K55n - 1366x768) and it kinda works but the border of the window I have open on the primary screen overlay into the secondary.

It's not visible on a screenshot but I took a photo of the issue with my phone so you have a better idea of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Tried googling for solutions to this issue but haven't found any that fixed it.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it myself!

I modified the monitors.xml file and change the monitor position manually on the X axis (it was set to 1050, changed it to 1060) and that annoying overlay is now gone.